# Ruby on Rails prevent Turbolinks from hijacking AJAX action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I am following along the RoR getting started guide and adding a few things as I go along. Specifically, what I would like to achieve is that in step [5.13 Deleting Articles](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-articles), I delete an article using AJAX instead of using the standard pattern.

I want to do so in a way that fits in best with the RoR way of doing things. After reading the [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) chapter, the following steps seemed like the way to go:

1. Add property `remote: true` to the `link_to` helper (See code snippet A)
2. Disable turbolinks this `link_to` helper by adding `data: {turbolinks: false}` (See code snippet A)
3. Add a some logic to the controller that will make sure JSON is returned (see code snippet B).
4. Add JavaScript that listens for the `ajax:success` events and then animates the item away (see code snippet C).

**Snippet A**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', 
        article_path(article),
        method: :delete,
        data: {turbolinks: false, remote: true},
        :class=> 'remove-article' %></td>
```

**Snippet B**

```
def destroy  
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.destroy
        format.html { redirect_to articles_path }
        format.json { render json: @article }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 
end
```

**Snippet C**

```
(function(){
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', listenForArticleDelete);

  function listenForArticleDelete() {
    $('a.remove-article').on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
      // e.preventDefault();
      console.log('DELETE: AJAX SUCCESS', e, '\n', data, '\n', status, '\n', xhr);
    });
  }
})();
```

This isn't quite working as I expected:

- The turbolinks disabling hasn't worked: it is still replacing the full page content.
- The event `ajax:success` event is triggered but when I inspect the data property of that event, I see some weird stuff. It seems a textual representation of what Turbolinks is about to do / has just done (?!). `Turbolinks.clearCache() Turbolinks.visit("http://localhost:3000/articles", {"action":"replace"})`

I am obviously doing this wrong. Can someone please explain to me how I should be doing this? I.e. not just how to get it to work, but also in an idiomatic RoR way?

---

#EDIT
I found out which part was the culprit: it was **Snippet B** because the format.html was being run before the format.json. Simply switching these two fixed the issue:

**Revised snippet A:**

```
<!-- Default delete -> format.html -->
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy default', 
        article_path(article),
        method: :delete,
        :class=> 'remove-article' %></td>
<!-- aSync delete -> format.json -->
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy aSync', 
        article_path(article),
        method: :delete,
        remote: true,
        data: {turbolinks: false},
        :class=> 'remove-article' %></td>
```

**Revised snippet B:**

```
def destroy  
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.destroy
        # Must place json before html, otherwise html will be executed
        format.json { render json: @article }
        format.html { redirect_to articles_path }
      else
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { render action: "index" }
      end
    end
 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would come at this a different way personally.

View:
trigger ajax call to delete article

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy default', article, method: :delete, :remote => true, :class=> 'remove-article' %></td>
```

Controller:

```
def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

this will process the destroy method and return javascript, by default this will return with the destroy.js.erb file in the relevant directory

destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#article").slideToggle(300, function(){

    $("#article").remove();

});
```

FYI: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Hope this helps somewhat

Comment: Thanks Brad, where does the file `destroy.js.erb` live? In the `\views\articles` folder?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed i missed the `:remote => true` bit off the link, Ill edit the answer

Comment: Thanks Brad. I am new to Rails and putting a js file in the views folder seemed like a bad idea to me, but after some Googling it does seem like 'The Rails way' to handle things. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the convention here is that this js is directly related to that particular view and nothing else. If it was a universal function, then add the function the the asset pipeline and use the .js.erb to call the function. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your Snippet A and using no_turbolink: true

**Snippet A**

```
<td data-no-turbolink="true"><%= link_to 'Destroy', 
        article_path(article),
        method: :delete,
        data: {no_turbolink: true, remote: true},
        :class=> 'remove-article' %></td>
```

Resulting link html should have the following code in it:

```
data-no-turbolink="true"
```

EDIT: Added data-no-turbolink="true" to the  tag, hopefully it helps there, the root of your problem is disabling turbolink, as soon as we achieve it I think you should be good.

[Opting out of Turbolink](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/blob/master/README.md#opting-out-of-turbolinks)

Comment: I tried this, and the resulting HTML now looks like this:
`<a data-no-turbolink="true" data-remote="true" class="remove-article" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles/38">Destroy</a>`
Unfortunately this didn't change anything

Comment: @Hendrik edited, added the data-no-turbolink="true" to td tag, give it a try please

Comment: OK, also added to the `<td>` now but still no luck
`<td data-no-turbolink="true"><a data-no-turbolink="true" data-remote="true" class="remove-article" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/articles/41">Destroy</a></td>`

Comment: thanks for sharing what you think the root of my problem is. I suspected the same thing. But currently these turbolinks seems pretty darn persistent. A colleague suggested opting out of turbolinks alltogether, but I think that would be a shame as they do work quite nicely on page transitions etc.

Comment: @Hendrik I know we need to concentrate on a problem at hand and hence I honestly can't fathom why Turbolinks would be so persistent in your case. Overall though it might be worthwhile actually going towards the direction your colleague mentioned. There is also a discrepancy on how to disable turbolinks for a specific element, some sources say data-no-turbolink="true" but others mention data-turbolinks="false". Also notice how its singular in one case and plural in second. I would try all combinations to see if any of them help. E.g. no_turbolinks: true turbolink: false and etc..

Comment: thanks for your help... I am starting to think it might be better to opt out of Turbolinks completely. The docs seem inacurate, for example:
`Also, Turbolinks is installed as the last click handler for links. So if you install another handler that calls event.preventDefault(), Turbolinks will not run.` I tried this but that is also not working.